# How many ways can $4$ distinguishable pieces be placed on an $8\times8$ chessboard, such that no $2$ pieces are in the same row or column?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question.** How many ways can a 4 distinguishable pieces be placed on an $8\times8$ chessboard, such that no 2 pieces are in the same row or column?

**Attempt.** I went ahead and gave it a drawing. My first thoughts were starting with a single piece placing it in one of the 64 places, then proceeded with trying to put up the next piece, but realised that now $(64-1)-7\cdot2=49$ places were left for the second one to be placed. Then I went with the 3rd piece, and realised there were $(49-1)-6\cdot 2=36$ places left for the 3rd piece, and $(36-1)-5\cdot 2=25$ left for the 4th final one. This could be transformed into a formula but I don't think it serves us here at all. My final answer was adding all of those 4, and I don't even know if it's right, but I'm trying to think of a combinatorics method with the Choose and Permutations and all of that.

Comment: Since you are counting how many ways each independent steps can be performed, you need to multiply the numbers $64\times 49 \times 36 \times 25$.

Comment: Oh! Great, but I'd still love to know how to think intuitively of an permutations/choose answer like $4!\binom{8}{4}\binom{8}{4}$

Comment: @Yorch That should be $4!^2\cdot \binom84^2$. The formula in your comment applies to identical pieces.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, you're right @MikeEarnest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, we first choose $4$ rows and $4$ columns which can be done in $\displaystyle {8 \choose 4} {8 \choose 4}$ ways.

Now as the pieces are distinct, we decide their order in rows in $4!$ ways and for each such order, we have $4!$ ways of ordering them in columns.

So total number of arrangements $\displaystyle  = 4! \ 4! {8 \choose 4} {8 \choose 4} $

Answer (score 2):

### A more systematic approach.

This problem isn't too hard if you think about it logically. For the first piece, you have $64$ choices. After placing this first piece, no matter where you placed it, you have removed $15$ available squares:

[image: img1]

This means you have $64-15=49$ choices for the next piece. After you place this piece, you will again remove $15$ available squares, minus the two intersections you will have with previously removed squares:

[image: img2]

This means that for the third piece, you have $49-13=36$ options. No matter which of these options you choose, you will remove $15$ available spots minus the $4$ intersections you will have with previously removed squares:

[image: img3]

So for the final piece you have $36-11=25$ options.

[image: img4]

### So our answer is
$$64\cdot 49\cdot 36\cdot 25=2~822~400$$

Which, as others have noted, is equal to

### $$4!^2\cdot {{}_8 C_4}^2$$